# Find coords of mouse cursor position in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, mouse, richtextbox

I want to find the X/Y pixel coordinates of the current mouse cursor position in a Winforms RichTextBox in C#. How do I go about this?

Comment: It depends what your input and output coordinates are? If you're in a MouseMove event you'll be using coordinates relative to the RichTextBox. This might also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913682/control-pointtoclient-vs-pointtoscreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Point p = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
int mx = richTextBox1.PointToClient(p).X;
int my = richTextBox1.PointToClient(p).Y;
```